# Accessing application deployed on cluster through fully qualified domain name instead of IP Address

Tags: rest, kubernetes, cluster-computing, endpoint, fully-qualified-naming

We have deployed our application on Gardener K8 cluster. Exposed one port xxxx for external traffic through Service Type LoadBalancer. Currently cloud provider is assigning 'external ip' to service, which keeps changing with every build/deployment. To solve this problem, I created dnsEntry as abc.xyz.somedomain.com and added configuration to said service under annotations field. While trying to access this service through postman as [http://abc.xyz.somedomain.com:xxxx//*apiname"](http://abc.xyz.somedomain.com:xxxx//*apiname%22), I am getting timed out error which works otherwise with external ip of service. Do I need to do some other configuration here before using dns name instead of external ip? Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide yaml files of deployment and service ?

Comment: @Malgorzata thanks for quick reply. Meanwhile I realized that I was trying to assign dnsrecord which was already assigned to other resource. Now I am able to access the service using dns name.

Comment: Please paste file in proper format into post, also paste deployment yaml. If problem is already solved post solution as an answer to be more visible for community.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are two ways to create dns record in cluster one with service and another with dnsentry resource type. I was trying to use both the options without realizing it, so it was complaining as dns record which I am trying to access second time is already assigned and busy. Now I have removed duplicate and its working fine.